# Metastock Script to Pine (Tradingview)

Tags: pine-script

Below is a simple code that I have used with Metastock.
I'm now trying to convert it to Pine for Tradeview.
I would be so happy if someone could give me some help and directions! =)

TO OPEN POSITION

```
atrp:= 14;
atrxl:= 3; {stop loss}
atrxp:= 3; {profit target}
ma1:= Mov(C,18,E);
ma2:= Mov(C,55,E);
bc:= ma1>ma2 AND ADX(14)>25 AND Cross(ma1,L);
trade:= If(PREV<=0, If(bc, C, 0),
If(L< PREV-(atrxl*ATR(atrp)), -1,
If(H> PREV+(atrxp*ATR(atrp)), -2, PREV)));
Cross(trade>0,0.5)
```

TO CLOSE POSITION

```
atrp:= 14;
atrxl:= 3; {stop loss}
atrxp:= 3; {profit target}
ma1:= Mov(C,18,E);
ma2:= Mov(C,55,E);
bc:= ma1>ma2 AND ADX(14)>25 AND Cross(ma1,L);
trade:= If(PREV<=0, If(bc, C, 0),
If(L< PREV-(atrxl*ATR(atrp)), -1,
If(H> PREV+(atrxp*ATR(atrp)), -2, PREV)));
Cross(0,trade)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [pinescript language reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/) but here are some equivalences

`Mov(C,18,E)` -> `ema(close,18)`

`ATR(atrp)` -> `atr(atrp)`

`If` -> `iff`

`Cross(0,trade)` -> `cross(0,trade)`

`PREV` is equal to the previous value of the variable, in pinescript all you need is to declare the variable beforehand:

```
a = 0.  
a := nz(a[1]) + close
```

This should be equivalent to

```
a = close + PREV
```